# Why not call a reference when swapping elements using simultaneous assignment?

Tags: python, list, swap

I have a question regarding swapping elements in python, for which i couldn't find an answer on the net. What is the difference between the both alternatives that I tried and why does only the second one give the expected output?
I worked on a selection sort algorithm and thus had to swap elements of a list. I had assigned the value of `max(my_list)` to the variable `max_item`.

(1) This was my first try swapping `max_item` and `my_list[-1]`:

```
max_item, my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], max_item
```

The actual output was:

```
[value of max_item, value of max_item]
```

(2) Then I tried the following:

```
my_list[my_list.index(max_item)], my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], my_list[my_list.index(max_item)]
```

This gave the expected output:

```
[value of my_list[-1], value of max_item]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you expect `max_item = my_list[-1]` to change the first element of `my_list`?

Comment: [mre] - not sure what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_item` has nothing to do with `my_list`, even if you do:

```
max_item = max(my_list)
```

The index in `my_list` that contains the maximal item and `max_item` are both *aliases* binding to the same underlying object, but when you reassign `max_item` (as opposed to mutating it in place, e.g. with a mutating method call, or reassigning one of its attributes), you *rebind* that name, breaking the aliasing, changing nothing in `my_list`.

Your second line of code works because you rebind the appropriate index in `my_list`. You only need to look it up for the reassignment though, so you could speed your code up and simplify a bit by using:

```
my_list[my_list.index(max_item)], my_list[-1] = my_list[-1], max_item
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give an example that illustrates what reassigning one of the (underying object's or `max_item` 's?) attributes means?

Comment: @puh_dormouse: If you'd did `max_item = my_list[0]`, then followed up with `max_item.attr = 123`, `my_list[0]` would also reflect the change (because both `max_item` and `my_list[0]` continue to alias the same object).